# Linq query with ToLower() on always encrypted column value returns error

Tags: c#, linq, always-encrypted

I have configured "always encrypted" columns in my database through SSMS. I have a linq query That simply checks to see if the string I'm passing through matches any records with the same string.

This linq query works:

```
appDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == userEmail);
```

However, I can't rely on exact string comparisons unless I convert to upper/lower casing. That said, this linq query doesn't work:

```
appDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email.ToLower() == userEmail.ToLower());
```

The specific error being:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Operand type clash:
> nvarchar(100) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC',
> encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
> column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1',
> column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MyDatabaseName') is incompatible with
> varchar Statement(s) could not be prepared.'

Can anyone advise why this is happening or how I can solve this?

Comment: You can't use functions on the column, because the server doesn't know the decryption key. You have to process the whole table client-side. The only way to do this server-side is to compare exactly. Your best bet is to always store it lower-case

Comment: Is the Email comng from the DB context encrypted at the point of comparison? if so the Hashbytes type is not compatible with a varchar.

Comment: @Charlieface I think I get it - is there anyway to add entities in this way (via linq)? I haven't been able to find how to online

Comment: can you try this once `appDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => String.Equals(x.Email , userEmail, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));`

Comment: No, you need to think carefullt about what you're asking the server to do. It can't do any conversion to the value, because it hasn't decrypted it. This is why an encrypted column needs to be a binary collation

Comment: @Charlieface how does it work with only `==` operator? If it doesn't know the decryption key

Comment: It is comparing the encrypted versions. The client knows the encryption so it can encrypt the parameter before it sends it to the server. The server can do an exact comparison of encrypted bytes. But the server can read the data, so it is unable to use a function such as `LOWER()` on it

Comment: @Charlieface - it's been a minute lol, but if you wanted to post an answer based on the comments you put in this question, I'll go ahead and accept it just to have it answered on SO.

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish `==` and `!=` work if you have Determistic Encryption, which means the value can be equality compared. No other comparisons or functions are possible, because the server cannot decrypt it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#limitations Deterministic encryption is a bit less secure, but obviously has querying benefits. Point is: the client is the only one who knows the key and is the only one who can decrypt the value, the server cannot do any computation on the decrypted value

Comment: Note also that `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is not going to be supported, as the server cannot do any collation conversion on the value, you can only use ordinal collations which end `_BIN2`

Comment: @Charlieface - I'm circling back to this question as I wanted to close this out. could you post an answer using your comments? You were right, just wanted to accept an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToLower()` translates to a call to `LOWER`. You can't use `LOWER` or any other function on an encrypted column, because the server (by design) cannot decrypt it, only the client can do that. It's basically a complete black box to the server.

**The only practical thing you can do with an encrypted column is return it to the client.** If Deterministic Encryption is used (a little less secure), then you can also do equality filters and joins, as well as grouping. But you *cannot* do anything else with the value, such as concatenation, function calls, collation changes, etc. You can't even use `>` or `LIKE` as that requires the server to know the inherent sort of the data, and you can't compare it to an unencrypted value from another table or a variable.

Note that you can't use a case-insensitive collation either, because the server cannot handle the sorting and filtering of such collations without knowing the actual value.

Your best bet is to just store it in lowercase to begin with.